# Bootstrap's modal is not popping up in Angular application?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm building an `EmailClient` app for my school project. Using `Bootstrap` for the UI.

I have three components (actually, I have four components if you count parent component which contains these three components), like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        
        <div c class="col-lg-3 ">  
            <app-folder-tree></app-folder-tree>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <app-message></app-message>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

My goal is to be able to open simple modal for editing any folder's name by double clicking on any folder. From `<app-folder-tree>` component, I'm using Telerik's [TreeView](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/data-binding/) UI component. Here is how `<app-folder-tree>` component looks like:

```
<div class="test">


    <kendo-treeview
        id="idt"
        [nodes]="folders"
        textField="folderName"
        [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
        [children]="fetchChildren" 
        (nodeDblClick)="doubleClick($event)" 
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
            
    
        (selectionChange)="handleSelection($event)"
            
        kendoTreeViewSelectable
        [selectBy]="'folderName'"
           
        >
    </kendo-treeview>

    <div *ngIf="showModalBox">


        <div class="container">
            <!-- Small modal -->
        
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                Content
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

And this is a function in `.ts` file:

```
  doubleClick($event){
    console.log("aaafff")
    this.showModalBox = true;
  }
```

[image]

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

instead of
`<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"`...

use ngClass to classes conditionally

`<div class="modal fade" [ngClass]="{'show d-block' : showModalBox}"`...

that will add class 'show' and 'd-block' when showModalBox is true removes when false / undefined / null

Comment: that div with *ngIf="showModalBox" is not required at all

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Or is it some kind of Angular library like ngxbootstrap in place ?

Comment: It is a regular bootstrap, version 4.6.0. I found this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-11-bootstrap-4-modal-exampleexample.html but with mdbootstrap, which I used in other project, modal functionality worked just fine... Standard bootstrap is causing problems, I'll probably switch to ngx or mdb if I don't find cleaner solution

Comment: BS4 use [ngClass]="{'show d-block' : showModalBox}" instead of  [class.show]="showModalBox" we need two classes